# Add STS reference missing in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, wif

Add STS reference (Preferably adding Create new STS Project) option is not available in Visual studio Ultimate with update 4. I have tried to install identity and access tool extension and it does not allow me to install since, it is expecting visual studio 2012 ultimate but not 2013 ultimate.
I have referred many MSDN blogs on this and every where they either talk about VS2012 or they talk about Fedutil tool of WIF sdk 4.0 which uses old version of WIF (Microsoft.IdentityModel) but not new version (System.IdentityModel).

From create project, i can somehow add reference to the STS project using "On-premises" option. But i want to create a STS project and then reference it.

Is there a way to add STS reference to any project in "Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version"

I referred Microsoft [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151.aspx) and i can use the existing samples they have provided but is there a Standard template available for the above said version of VS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FedUtil and the "Identity and Access Tool" are no longer available.

The only way to do this is via "Change Authentication" when you create the project and then select "On Premise". Unfortunately, you can only do this when you create the project. You can't retrofit it afterwards. I believe this is changing in VS 2015.

Part of the reason for the tools disappearing is that these tools were WIF based whereas OWIN is the basis for all new VS development.

You can merge the WIF section from the web.config of an old WIF project.

Refer : [Visual Studio : No STS tool](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/05/visual-studio-no-sts-tool.html) .

Comment: Yep, taking a working configuration from elsewhere is a shortest and easiest way. The "Add STS reference..." doesn't do much more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. though the next one is also an exact answer, i have to mark that since it is from msdn. but this in readable format.

Comment: Actually. there is no rule that MSDN content takes precedence. You should mark the "best" answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers. How you select the "best" answer is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Microsoft did not include the "Identity and Access" tool to VS 2013. Also, there is no template as far as I am aware of.

There are however two tricks that you can use to create a claims aware App in VS 2013:
1- You can create the same project in VS 2012 and import it to VS 2013 and this will work.
2- You can add the System.IdentityModel tags yourself in your VS 2013 project as described here: [What do I need to build a claims-aware wcf service in VS 2013?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/napegadie_kones_msft_blog/archive/2015/04/03/what-do-i-need-to-build-a-claims-aware-wcf-service-in-vs-2013.aspx)

The following link can help as well: [Claims Aware WCF using WIF in .Net 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/napegadie_kones_msft_blog/archive/2015/02/10/claims-aware-wcf-using-wif-in-net-4-5.aspx)